# Want to bind events on scrolling with the use of smooth scrollbar js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, smooth-scrolling, smoothing

How are you all?

I am using Smooth Scrollbar Js as per client requirement. I want to bind events on scrolling but I am unable to bind.

Can anyone help me please?

Here is the link of Smooth Scrollbar JS

https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean by "_bind events on scrolling_"? Which specific events are you refering to?

Comment: I want to add custom positions to div or images on scrolling. But I need to use smooth scrollbar as per client requirements.